# Get data from New York Times API JSON response

Tags: php, json, api, loops, decode

I'm currently working with NewYorkTimes news API. I receive this JSON response. And now I want to loop through it using PHP and get each of articles (image, title and excerpt).

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2017 The New York Times Company. All Rights Reserved.",
  "response": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "web_url": "https://www.nytimes.com/reuters/2017/11/15/business/15reuters-square-bitcoin.html",
        "snippet": "Payments company Square Inc said it has started allowing select customers to buy and sell bitcoins on its Cash app, as it looks to tap into a craze that has sent the cryptocurrency up nearly sevenfold this year.",
        "blog": {},
        "source": "Reuters",
        "multimedia": [],
        "headline": {
          "main": "Payments Company Square Tests Bitcoin Buying and Selling",
          "print_headline": "Payments Company Square Tests Bitcoin Buying and Selling"
        },
        "keywords": [],
        "pub_date": "2017-11-15T18:24:36+0000",
        "document_type": "article",
        "new_desk": "None",
        "byline": {
          "original": "By REUTERS"
        },
        "type_of_material": "News",
        "_id": "5a0c866b7c459f246b6349f9",
        "word_count": 388,
        "score": 2.5538578,
        "uri": "nyt://article/1dff4a88-4086-507c-b644-33e0d7d95e28"
      },
      {
        "web_url": "https://www.nytimes.com/reuters/2017/11/13/business/13reuters-investment-summit-fink-bitcoin.html",
        "snippet": "Bitcoin, whose value has fluctuated significantly this month, remains a \"speculative\" investment that thrives because of the cryptocurrency's anonymous nature, BlackRock Inc Chief Executive Larry Fink said on Monday.",
        "blog": {},
        "source": "Reuters",
        "multimedia": [],
        "headline": {
          "main": "BlackRock's Fink Says Bitcoin Thrives on Its Anonymity",
          "print_headline": "BlackRock's Fink Says Bitcoin Thrives on Its Anonymity"
        },
        "keywords": [],
        "pub_date": "2017-11-13T17:45:33+0000",
        "document_type": "article",
        "new_desk": "None",
        "byline": {
          "original": "By REUTERS"
        },
        "type_of_material": "News",
        "_id": "5a09da4a7c459f246b63428d",
        "word_count": 322,
        "score": 2.5538578,
        "uri": "nyt://article/bb396871-c686-5afc-9e71-3f9f5af8dac1"
      }
    ],
    "meta": {
      "hits": 959,
      "offset": 0,
      "time": 7
    }
  }
}
```

Firstly I used  `$arr = json_decode($result);` to decode my json. 
But when I tried to make a loop it doesnt return me anything

```
foreach($arr['docs'] as $article){
    echo $article['web_url'];
}
```

Please help me to loop through this JSON response and get neccessary data. Thank you!

Comment: It's not an array but an object. Use `$arr = json_decode($result, true);` instead to get an array. And then it should be `$arr['response']['docs']`. Or loop over `$arr->response->docs`

Comment: I changed my code, but it still returns me anything...

Comment: Sorry didn't check your updated answer. It's working!

Comment: `foreach($arr['response']['docs'] as $article){`

Comment: @jeroen Can I make smth like this? `foreach($arr->response->docs as $article){
    echo $article->web_url;
  }`

Comment: Yes, if use json_decode without `true`

Comment: @splash58 Hi man.
Is it possible to foreach only first 9 elements (articles in my case)?
Because for now I receive 10 articles from JSON and I want to work only with first 9.

Comment: use `for` loop from 0 to 8 or add counter and break foreach

Comment: Sorry but any example?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);
foreach($json['response']['docs'] as $key => $value)
{
  if(!empty($value['web_url']))
  {
   $WEB= $value['web_url'];
   $WEB= addslashes($WEB);
   $WEB= trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $WEB));
  }
  else
  {
    $WEB= '';
  }
   echo 'WEB= '.$WEB.'</br>';
}
```

just make sure the foreach is true, maybe can help.